# How to solve jQuery collision Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two jQuery one is 
 and the other one is  if i remove first one the slider starts working and if i remove the second one then the dropdown starts working. I have seen other tutorials on the net of how to solve collision but i was unable to solve it.Please help. Code is written below.

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="caption/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="caption/jquery.capSlide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".capslide_img_cont12").capslide({
            caption_color:'#bfedfa',
            caption_bgcolor:'#000',
            overlay_bgcolor:'#000',
            showcaption: false
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.6.pack.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).on('ready post-load', easy_fancybox_handler );
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use `noConflict()` to solve this. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: What did you try from other tutorials and what went wrong?

Comment: 2 versions of jQuery = bad idea

Comment: which version of jQuery should i use to avoid conflict.

Comment: @epascarello yes, 2 version of jQuery is poor syntax, but it shouldn't effect this. The browser only uses the last-loaded version

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

So, basically:

After including `jquery.js`:

```
<script>
   var $jQ = $.noConflict();  // use $jQ instead of $ for normal jQuery
</script>
```

And use just `$` after including `jQuery 1.3.2`

I do believe that you have very strong reasons for having included 2 versions of jQuery, otherwise its a Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="caption/jquery.capSlide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="caption/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script>
   var $jQ = $.noConflict(true);  

           jQ(function() {

Comment: which version of jQuery should i use to avoid conflict.

Comment: @user3026519 just use a higher version and don't include two jquery